# Test if a string is a valid, unquoted identifier?

Tags: postgresql, string, regclass, identifier

I'm just wondering if there is an established method for testing if a string can be used as an *unquoted* PostgreSQL identifier? (unquoted because almost any string can be a quoted identifier).

I ask because as shown in a previous question ([How to quote qualified table name with format() function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200419)), there are times when I would need to specify an identifier (such as the name of a table to be created) that does not yet exist, as string values (`text`) instead of a safer type such as `regclass`. Quoting the string/name can be problematic as shown there and probably else where. Without quoting, it's susceptible to SQL injection.

I guess if one programs it hard enough, a string parsing function can be written ultimately. Just wanted to check if there are existing solutions.

Related:

[What are the valid formats of a PostgreSQL schema name?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45589)

[Is the function PARSENAME() the opposite of QUOTENAME()](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196015) (sql-server)

Comment: `select format('%I','foo') = 'foo' as is_valid`?

Comment: Let's suppose such a function existed. If you give it `foo.bar`, how it's supposed to know whether you mean table `bar` in schema `foo`, in which case it doesn't need to be quoted, or you mean table `foo.bar` in the current schema, in which case it must be quoted?

Comment: @DanielVérité `foo.bar` would be invalid as an unquoted ident, as it contains a dot `.`, wouldn't it? The answer here (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45591/55439) mentions only underscore and dollar sign as acceptable non-letter characters.

Comment: I thought you wanted to accept `schema.table` just like the SQL parser does, as your related question says _qualified table name with format()_. If not, the suggestion by @a_horse_with_no_name seems to answer the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your comment. If you convert it to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using based on @a_horse_with_no_name's comment.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_unqualid(_ident text)
 RETURNS bool AS $func$
  SELECT format('%I',lower(_ident)) = lower(_ident);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

The idea is that the `format` function (with `%I`) will **not** add any quotes if it is unnecessary (i.e. when the input is already a simple identifier). I also normalized identifier names to lower cases using `lower()` before the comparison, which may or may not be desirable depending on whether the identifiers are supposed to be case insensitive or sensitive.

Sample output:

```
=> SELECT is_unqualid('Ab'), is_unqualid('ab'), is_unqualid('a b'), is_unqualid('a. b');
 is_unqualid | is_unqualid | is_unqualid | is_unqualid 
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
 t           | t           | f           | f
(1 row)
```